# Iphone Keyboard Is Changing Zoom Scale of My Web Site

Tags: iphone, keyboard, zooming

Anyone know how to prevent the zoom that happens when keyboard/spinner is displayed?

I do know that if you set meta tag viewport content to "user-scalable=no" then this zooming is not being done, but is there any way to prevent this anoying zoom without cutting all zooming functionality for users?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Clarification: Are you asking how to modify the website or are you asking how to modify a webview in an app?

Comment: Sorry about confusion, I m asking about website (javascript, metatags, or any other tip) as this happens also in safari browser.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing I found out that depending on viewport size zoom is not made. I mean when having viewport:

```
 <meta name="viewport"  content="user-scalable=yes, width=280px" />
```

With no maximum-scale, nor initial-scale, then safari browser wont zoom in when keyboard/spinner is displayed.

I do not understand very well this behaviour, as I would say that logical width to avoid this zooming should be 320px...

I wont mark it as answer, just in case someone wants to add more light to this issue...

Comment: Not sure how it works either, but you solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I have no maximum-scale or initial-scale set and my page is still zooming when the keyboard opens. I'm really not keen on setting a pixel width in viewport - feels like it could have consequences far beyond fixing this iphone issue. Currently I dont have a better idea though ...

Answer (score 2):

Prevent zooming all together by adding this meta tag to your head tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"/>
```

more solutions:
https://blog.osmosys.asia/2017/01/05/prevent-ios-from-zooming-in-on-input-fields/

Comment: Nice answer, you save me